# function in JavaScript not work it the html

Tags: javascript, html, css

### I trying write my first site and I don't know why js file doesn't work.

Maybe you can repair that. I can't write that, because I'm learning to program.

**HTML** here

```
<head>  

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

        </script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Makoto Designer</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>

</head>

<body>  
        <header>
                <div id="hed">
                <img src="/img/logo_okr.png" class="logo">
                <div class="biale"></div>
                <div class="czarne"></div>
                <img src="/img/md.png" class="md">
                </div>
        </header>
</body>
```

---

**CSS** here

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 3;
}

.md {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 532px;
    height: 190px;
    left: 230px;
    top: 18px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}


.czarne {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #00000099;
    z-index: 1;
}


.biale {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 125px;
    top: 55px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}   

.biale.on {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 125px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 155px;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 75px;
    border-top-right-radius: 75px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 7px 10px #00000066);
}
```

---

**JavaScript** here

```
function handleClicks() {
    var logo = $(".logo"),
        biale = $(".biale"),
        czarne = $(".czarne"),

        var menu = {
        open: () => {
            biale.addCalss("active");
            czarne.fadeTo("fast", 1, () => czarne.show());
        },
        close: () => {
            biale.removeClass("active");
            czarne.fadeTo("fast", 0, () => czarne.hide());
        }
        };

        logo.click(() => menu.open());
        czarne.click(() => {
            menu.close();
        });

}

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let biale = $(".biale")[0]
    let logo = $(".logo")[0]
    let toggle = false
    logo.addEventListener('clock', () => {
        toggle = !toggle
        biale.className = toggle ? 'on' : ""
    })
})
```

---

**I want `biale` to slide behind the `logo` and then hide, but wen i click logo nothing happens. Why it not working?**

mehh

Comment: set the src for your script tag to point to your file

Comment: I have src in script tag.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your CSS, change .biale.on to .biale.active

You may want to look at this for help with your HTML file: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Some changes you'll want to do:

1. Add doctype
2. Remove that empty js script in head for cleanliness. I'm assuming your JavaScript is going to be in the javas.js file.

Here's what your HTML could look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Makoto Designer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="hed">
        <!-- Don't forget to close your img tags like this. Do the second one too. -->
        <img src="/img/logo_okr.png" class="logo" />
        <div class="biale"></div>
        <div class="czarne"></div>
        <img src="/img/md.png" class="md">
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
        <!-- Also close html at the end -->
</html>
```

In your javas.js file, try making these changes:

1. Remove the , comma at the end of the last var declaration. I eliminated the shortcut altogether below.
2. There was a typo with addClass.
3. I'm not sure you need the addEventListener. jQuery allows you to use its document ready feature to call your handleClicks function on load in order to set up the fades.

Here's an example:

```
function handleClicks() {
  var logo = $(".logo");
  var biale = $(".biale");
  var czarne = $(".czarne");
  var menu = {
      open: () => {
          biale.addClass("active");
          czarne.fadeTo("fast", 1, () => czarne.show());
      },
      close: () => {
          biale.removeClass("active");
          czarne.fadeTo("fast", 0, () => czarne.hide());
      }
  };

  logo.click(() => menu.open());
  czarne.click(() => {
        menu.close();
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  handleClicks();
});
```

Comment: I have doctype, but I don't give it in question, because i couldn't publish this question.

Comment: [files of my site](https://github.com/MakotoDesignerPL/makotodesignerpl.github.io)
   [my site](https://makotodesignerpl.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `<script>` in the bottom of body tag (not in head) - and also put semiclon after `czarne = $(".czarne");` (not comma `,`)

Comment: I can give you link to my site on github.
[link](https://makotodesignerpl.github.io/)

Comment: [github](https://github.com/MakotoDesignerPL/makotodesignerpl.github.io)
[site](https://makotodesignerpl.github.io/)